# How to derive the principle value of the exponential integral ($\mathrm{Ei}(x)$) when $x>0$?

Tags: improper-integrals

I am trying to derive the value of the exponential integral $\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{e^{t}}{t}\mathrm{d}t$ when $x>0$. I understand that we are integrating through a singularity at $x=0$, so I tried to use the PV in Cauchy's sense, here is what I came up so far:
\begin{align*}
  &\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{e^{t}}{t}\mathrm{d} t=\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{e^{t}}{t}\mathrm{d} t+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{e^{t}}{t}\mathrm{d} t=\lim_{\delta\to 0}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\delta}\frac{e^{t}}{t}\mathrm{d} t+\int_{\delta}^{x}\frac{e^{t}}{t}\mathrm{d} t\right)\\
  =&\lim_{\delta\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{t}}{t}\bigg|_{-\infty}^{-\delta}-\int_{-\infty}^{-\delta}(-1)\frac{e^{t}}{t^{2}}\mathrm{d} t+\frac{e^{t}}{t}\bigg|_{\delta}^{x}-\int_{\delta}^{x}(-1)\frac{e^{t}}{t^{2}}\mathrm{d} t\right)\\
  =&\lim_{\delta\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{-\delta}}{-\delta}-\lim_{t\to-\infty}\frac{e^{t}}{t}+\int_{-\infty}^{-\delta}\frac{e^{t}}{t^{2}}\mathrm{d} t+\frac{e^{x}}{x}-\frac{e^{\delta}}{\delta}+\int_{\delta}^{x}\frac{e^{t}}{t}\mathrm{d} x\right)\\
  =&\frac{e^{x}}{x}+\lim_{\delta\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{-\delta}}{-\delta}-\frac{e^{\delta}}{\delta}\right)+\lim_{\delta\to 0}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\delta}\frac{e^{t}}{t^{2}}\mathrm{d} t+\int_{\delta}^{x}\frac{e^{t}}{t^{2}}\mathrm{d} x\right)
\end{align*}
The $\lim_{t\to-\infty}\frac{e^{t}}{t}$ is simply zero, that much I understand. I also expect the same method (integral by parts) can be applied infinitely to generate a series form of the value. However I am troubled by the $\lim_{\delta\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{-\delta}}{-\delta}-\frac{e^{\delta}}{\delta}\right)$ part. One would the two fractions to cancel each other so the term is zero, but obviously it diverges. Is there anything I did wrong?

TIA

Comment: I expect it is zero as $e^t/t\sim1/t$ near $t=0$. You’ve likely made a sign error

Comment: @FShrike That was the first thing I have thought of, but I checked and found none of such mistakes, so I may have something conceptually wrong.

Comment: Interesting by parts to get a series won’t work I don’t think. The error term won’t go to zero

Comment: What you have written is correct until the last step, where you wrongly assumed that both of those limits exist.

Comment: Well, neither of them exist, but that was how the concept of "principle value" comes in, is it not?